# Listview with button below not working properly

Tags: android, listview, button, dialog

I have a ListView in a dialog and I need to show a button after the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">  
<TextView   android:id="@+id/tvwGameOver" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="25sp" android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<LinearLayout 
  android:id="@+id/lloPlayerNames" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:orientation="horizontal" android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
  android:headerDividersEnabled="true" android:layout_below="@id/tvwGameOver">
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwGameNumberHeader" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/scores_GameNumber" android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="13sp"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer0Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="12sp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="13sp"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer1Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
     android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="13sp"/>
  <TextView     
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer2Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
     android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="13sp"/>
  <TextView     
    android:id="@+id/tvwPlayer3Name" android:layout_weight="1" android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="13sp"/>
</LinearLayout>


  <ListView
   android:id="@+id/lvwScores" android:layout_below="@id/lloPlayerNames"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:divider="#FFFFFF" android:dividerHeight="1dip" 
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:footerDividersEnabled="true" android:headerDividersEnabled ="true"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/btnOK" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="120dip" 
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="OK" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 

   />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem is that when the list gets to be too big it just passes the button and the button sits over the top of the list.

I tried to add android:layout_below="@id/lvwScores" to the button but then, when the list is empty, I get a button that runs from the bottom of the screen to the bottom of the list.

If I remove the android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" then the dialog is made small.

At the end of the day, I am looking to have the list filling most of the screen even if part of it is still empty (it is a scores screen), with the button at the bottom.

Any ideas?

This is what it looks like when empty:
[image]

It is great, except that when the list builds up and reaches the bottom is down not stop at the button.

Comment: What's the point of the RelativeLayout? To always have the button at the bottom? Why not just use a LinearLayout and give the ListView a weight of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you maybe give the list view or the list view's container a margin at the bottom that is the height of the button?  Just as a test, give the button a height of 30 dips and have the listview or listview's container have a bottom margin of 30 dips to see if it still runs over behind the button.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Will take a few minutes to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The button should have 
`android:layout_below="@id/lvwScores"`

alignParentBottom isn't the best approach for RelativeLayouts that do not fill_parent.

Comment: Problem is that I want the list to fill the dialog even when it is empty. See edit.